# How can I measure the time of a drag on my Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

I want to measure the time of a drag. From the beginning(when the player touches the screen) to the end(when the player releases his finger from the screen).
In addition, I want to measure the distance of the drag to calculate the velocity of the drag.

But I always get the following two error messages.

1)When I touche the screen I get this error message in the first line of the foreach loop:

```
GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
```

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

2)The second error message is in this line:

```
DragTime = (float)(EndTime - StartTime);
```

Cannot convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'float'

What is wrong? What can I do to fix the error messages?

Here is my code:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Vector2 DragVelocity;
    TimeSpan StartTime;
    DateTime EndTime;
    float DragTime;
    Vector2 StartPoint, EndPoint, DragDistance;
    bool FirstTimePressed = true;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
        InactiveSleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.FreeDrag;
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
        foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
        {
            GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            if (FirstTimePressed == true)
            {
              if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed))
              {
                StartTime = gs.Timestamp;
                StartPoint = gs.Delta;
                FirstTimePressed = false;
              }
            }
            if ((tl.State == TouchLocationState.Released))
            {
                EndTime = DateTime.Now;
                DragTime = (float)(EndTime - StartTime);
                EndPoint = gs.Delta;
                DragDistance = EndPoint - StartPoint;
                DragVelocity = DragDistance / DragTime;
                FirstTimePressed = true;
            }
        }

        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            switch (gs.GestureType)
            {
                case GestureType.FreeDrag:

                break;
            }
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you use and handle the drag and drop events?

Comment: Which drag and drop events? I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would do it this way- when user presses the screen for the first time, set a global variable `TimeSpan time` to `TimeSpan.Zero`. Then, on every update, add `gameTime.ElapsedRealTime` to time variable. When user releases, your can get your time from time variable, it's easy. To get seconds just use: `time.totalSeconds`.

I've modified your code a little, here you go:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    float DragVelocity, DragDistance, DragTime;
    TimeSpan time;
    Vector2 StartPoint, EndPoint;
    bool isThisFirstTime = true;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
        InactiveSleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.DragComplete | GestureType.FreeDrag;
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            switch (gs.GestureType)
            {
                case GestureType.FreeDrag:
                    if (isThisFirstTime == true)
                    {
                        time = TimeSpan.Zero;
                        StartPoint = gs.Position;
                        isThisFirstTime = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        EndPoint = gs.Position;
                        time += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
                    }
                    break;

                case GestureType.DragComplete:
                    isThisFirstTime = true;
                    DragTime = (float) time.TotalSeconds;
                    DragDistance = Vector2.Distance(StartPoint, EndPoint);
                    DragVelocity = DragDistance / DragTime;
                    break;
            }
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx. It works. But sometimes, if I perform very short drag, the variable DragVelocity has not a normal value, but it just says Infinity. Why is this sometimes happening when I perform a very short drag?
How can I check if the value is Infinity? I want to write something on the screen if the value is Infinity, for example: "Please, perform a new drag". I tried it with the following code, but it's not working: if (DragVelocity == Infinity)

Comment: `FreeDrag` gesture is detected after a fixed length of movement, this means that if your drag is too short the game won't detect it, and I think that results in `DragVelocity = DragDistance / DragTime` where `DragTime` is 0.

Comment: And if you want to check whether float is a positive infinity and then do sth, just use this:
'if (float.IsPositiveInfinity(DragVelocity))
DrawText("blabla)'

check out how to drawtext in xna.